# Although byteval is declared as an integer in write(), why only the low-order eight bits are written to the file in Java I/O streams

Tags: java, unicode, io, stream

From an abstract given in ***Herbert Schildt*** book on ***Java***.

To write to a file, you can use the ***write( )*** method defined by ***FileOutputStream***. 
Its simplest form is shown here:

```
void write(int byteval) throws IOException
```

This method ***writes*** the ***byte*** specified by ***byteval*** to the file. Although ***byteval*** is declared as an integer, only the ***low-order eight bits*** are written to the file.

Does that means only 2^8 = 256 combinations can be written. What if we have to include the ***Extended ASCII*** or ***Unicode*** ones.

Secondly,

Java defines two types of ***streams***: ***byte*** and ***character***. Byte streams provide a convenient means for handling input and output of bytes. Byte streams are used, for example, when reading or writing binary data. Character streams provide a convenient means for handling input and output of characters. They use Unicode and, therefore, can be internationalized. Also, in some cases, character streams are more efficient than byte streams.

```
At the lowest level, all I/O is still byte-oriented. The character-based streams simply provide a  
convenient and efficient means for handling characters.
```

Console output is most easily accomplished with *print( )* and ***println( )***. These methods are defined by the class ***PrintStream*** (which is the type of ***object*** referenced by ***System.out***). Even though ***System.out*** is a **byte stream**, using it for simple program output is still acceptable.
Because ***PrintStream*** is an output stream derived from ***OutputStream***, it also implements the low-level method *write*( ). Thus, ***write***( ) can be used to write to the ***console***. The simplest form of write( ) defined by ***PrintStream*** is shown here:

```
void write(int byteval)
```

This method writes to the stream the byte specified by byteval. Although byteval is declared as an integer, only the low-order eight bits are written. Here is a short example that uses write( ) to output the character “A” followed by a newline to the screen:

```
class WriteDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

    int b;
    b = 'A';
    System.out.write(b);
    System.out.write('\n');
    System.out.write(65);
    System.out.write('\n');
    System.out.write('A');
    System.out.write('\n');

  }
}
```

Output:

```
A
A
A
```

Even though ***System.out*** is a **byte stream**, then why does it output in the form of Characters and not in the form of bytes.
(Or Am i taking it wrong. Byte Streams have nothing to do with the representation of the output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside your Java program everything is a stream of bytes.

In Java, streams are raw bytes.  You can use streams directly to access the external data in its 'native' unmodified form.

Java *readers* are wrappers around streams that convert between bytes and characters (16-bit entities) using some encoding convention (i.e. UTF-8, ISO-8850-1).

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`, which is kind of a hybrid.  It is fundamentally a byte stream, so `write(65)` writes the ASCII character `A`.  However, `PrintStream` also happens to include some methods that use the system default encoding to convert `Character` and `String` values to bytes.  So if your default encoding was UTF-8 you could write

```
char uc = '÷';         // Unicode 0x00f7
System.out.print(uc);
```

The output would be a 2-byte sequence `0xC3,0xB7` which is the UTF-8 encoding of the `÷` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Because System.out is a PrintStream by default assigned (console output) any call to System.out.write(int) will convert the int value to an ASCII char.

So if you want to print 65 you must System.out.write("65");

Everything depends on the Stream assigned to your writer.